# How could this code be improved

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a way to avoid declaring `return_with_nok` two times but still catching both cases. Is there a way to write this code less verbose than the current one?

```
def receive_notification(params)
  if some_condition
    case params[:case]
      when 'case2'
        ... logic...
      when 'case2'
        ... logic...
        end
      else 
        return_with_nok
    end
  else 
    return_with_nok
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the part that starts the second `else` clause.

Comment: I agree with @tadman, something isn't balanced.  Case-when-when-else-end is valid.  but then there's an extra else-end that doesn't pair up

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
def receive_notification(params)
  return 'c' unless params.is_a?(Hash)

  case params[:case]
  when 'case1'
    'a'
  when 'case2'
    'b'
  else 
    'c'
  end
end
```

**Edit**

Your new example still seems to have an `end` beneath logic which does not belong there, in any case I would prefer refactoring it as follows using a guard clause over a conditional.

```
def receive_notification(params)
  return return_with_nok unless some_condition

  case params[:case]
  when 'case2'
    ..logic..
  when 'case2'
    ..logic..
  else 
    return_with_nok
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of doing this which might end up being more ugly than your less than pristine original code:

```
case some_condition && params[:case]
when ...
else
  # ...
end
```

If you can combine the conditions into a singular value you throw into your `case` statement you can do it that way. This might be a little hard to follow for those unfamiliar with how `&&` is evaluated.

I'd advocate going with the least confusing option even at the expense of a little bit of verbosity.

Another way to tackle the problem is to head it off in advance, flattening your logic one level:

```
return ... unless (some_condition)

case (...)
  # ...
end
```

That you'll have a duplicated function call is perhaps a problem of how your logic is structured. It really depends.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be satisfied by adding explicit returns in your `case`, and relying on fall-through?

```
def receive_notification(params)
  if some_condition
    case params[:case]
      when 'case1'
        ... logic...
        return something1
      when 'case2'
        ... logic...
        return something2
    end
  end
  return_with_nok
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit strange, but you could do:

`params[:case] = 'else' unless some_condition`

Or like this, so you don't change the user parameters:

```
kase = some_condition ? params[:case] : 'else'
case kase
  #...
```

Then you would end up in the else if the condition is not matched.